# Pegar múltiples vectores sin usar rbind

Tags: r

Tengo 10 vectores en mi entorno R, Quiero pegar estos vectores para crear un data.frame. Utilicé la función rbind, pero creo que es muy ineficiente, porque tengo que escribir todas las variables en la función. La pregunta es, ¿puedo usar la función paste0 o paste u otra función como esa, para pegar estos vectores ?, gracias.

```
#Por ejemplo

x1 <- c(1, 2)
x2 <- c(3, 4)
x3 <- c(5, 6)
x4 <- c(7, 8)
x5 <- c(9, 10)
x6 <- c(11, 12)
x7 <- c(13, 14)
x8 <- c(15, 16)
x9 <- c(17, 18)
x10 <- c(19, 30)

rbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)
```

Quiero pegar estos dos vectores, con alguna función similar a paste0 o paste.

Comment: por favor traduce tu pregunta, estas en la versión en español de SO, en caso contrario tu pregunta será cerrada

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro, el tema es que con `paste0()` generas los nombres de las variables, ahora el problema es como acceder a las mismas por el valor de estas cadenas y la respuesta es [`get()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html). En definitiva puedes hacer esto:

```
t(sapply(paste0("x",1:10), get))

x1     1    2
x2     3    4
x3     5    6
x4     7    8
x5     9   10
x6    11   12
x7    13   14
x8    15   16
x9    17   18
x10   19   30
```

Con `sapply()` generamos un loop implícito por cada nombre de variable, y a cada una le aplicamos [`get()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html), finalmente transponemos los datos para terminar  con una matriz similar a lo que buscas y que fácilmente puede llevarse a un `data.frame`

Nota: para estos casos resulta más conveniente tener estos vectores en una lista y acceder a los mismos desde la lista, si eventualmente ya los tendrías en una lista `z` podrías hacer:

```
z <- list(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)
t(sapply(z,rbind))
```